# Auth Dialogue loads in canvas first

Tags: php, facebook

When a user lands on my app and has not gone thru the authorise process the dialogue opens in the canvas first then reloads outside of the canvas. Apart from not looking quite right for a few seconds everything performs as expected.

I use `header('Location:https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=12345678910&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/namespace/&state=&scope=');`
at the top of my app should it be detected that authentication has not been accepted.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use a JavaScript redirect becuase a canvas application is already inside an iFrame and we want to redirect the top window to the authentication dialog.

Try this PHP function that echo's out a JavaScript redirect.

```
function jsRedirect($url){
    echo "<script language=javascript>";
    echo "top.location.href ='".$url."';";
    echo "</script>";
    exit();
}
```

Notice that we use `top.location.href` as opposed to `window.location.href`.

Comment: No worries!  Remember that when you are at apps.facebook.com, you are always inside an iFrame.